# toRightOf not working as expected in an android layout

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/outerBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/checksHere"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:columnWidth="100dp" />

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/textHere"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/checksHere"
    android:columnCount="4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"
    android:layout_width="185dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/outerBox"
    android:layout_below="@id/textHere"
    android:layout_margin="3dip"
    android:onClick="submit"
    android:text="@string/submit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_width="185dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textHere"
    android:layout_margin="3dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/submitButton"
    android:onClick="next"
    android:text="@string/cancel" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_width="185dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textHere"
    android:layout_margin="3dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cancelButton"
    android:onClick="next"
    android:text="test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a relative layout.  The layout has two grid layouts at the top, which can be populated in my java code with text or checks.  They can be blank.  Then I have three buttons.  The first two buttons display on the screen just fine.  The third button just sits on top of the first button:
[image]

I changed the third button (backButton) to be toRightOf submitButton just to see what would happen.  It goes on top of the cancelButton, as expected.  I feel like I'm missing a simple fundamental, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: could you try to remove `android:layout_below="@id/textHere"` from your last button?

Comment: It goes to the top of the layout, with the same X position as before.

Comment: and you have cleaned the project to make sure? sometimes the build process "forgets" the xml parsing...

Comment: @clavio try `layout_alignParentLeft="true"` on the left-most button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this doesn't necessarily fix the problem with RelativeLayout, but you could always group the three buttons together in a single LinearLayout. This should prevent the buttons from overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but when testing in eclipse changing all the `android:layout_width="185dip"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for buttons worked for me.